# Getting error "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker." setting up messaging with Sveltekit

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, sveltekit

Full error message

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed
to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-
push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP 
response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-
worker-registration).
    at it.<anonymous> (window-controller.ts:166:27)
    at tslib.es6.js:100:23
    at Object.throw (tslib.es6.js:81:53)
    at i (tslib.es6.js:72:64)
```

Contents of `src/service-worker.js`

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-app.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-messaging.js")

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: '...',
    projectId: '...',
    storageBucket: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
    appId: '...',
})

const messaging = firebase.messaging()
```

Contents of `src/firebase-messaging-sw`

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-app.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-messaging.js")

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': "..."
})

const messaging = firebase.messaging()

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then(function (registration) {
            console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
        });
}
```

contents of `src/jsconfig.json`

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.svelte",
    "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
]
```

method that's calling firebase-messaging

```
messaging
    .requestPermission() //It takes permission from user whether website can send notifications.
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.', res)
        if (messaging.getToken()) {

            // THIS PROMISE SHOWS "pending" WITH STATE "rejected".
            console.log('Token will come.', messaging.getToken())
        }
        return messaging.getToken()
    })
    .then(token => {
        console.log(`token`, token)
    })
    .catch(error => {

        // ERROR COMES FROM HERE
        console.log('error under got token.', error)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        errorElement.innerHTML = ErrElem.innerHTML + '; ' + err
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err)
    })
```

As a "throwing it against the wall to see what sticks", `firebase-messaging-sw.js` was added to jsconfig.json.

Chrome network tab shows `firebase-messaging-sw` as "pending", size "0 bytes".

Basically, it looks like this file is being missed. The serviceworker does it's job, and then when firebase comes back looking for this script in the root of the project, it either can't or won't find it.

How do I setup so that firebase can find this script?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add empty `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file to your `[YOUR_PROJECT]/public` folder.

The goal is to have `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file straight in `[YOUR_PROJECT]/dist` folder for firebase to be able to fetch it from server.
Svelte is automatically copying files from `public` to `dist` while building the app.

Answer (score 0):

I placed both scripts at the static folder and it worked in localhost at least